# Can stationarity only be assessed in the residuals, or it has to be assessed for the dependent variable as well?

Tags: residuals, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Can someone only test for stationarity in the residuals of a regression model? Or one has to test for stationarity in the dependent variable as well?

In other words, if residuals are stationary, everything is fine and nothing more needs to be looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for stationarity in either. However, if there seems to be a linear trend you would need to capture that to achieve stationarity. To test if you’ve captured the trend, and thus achieved stationarity, you test that in the residuals.

So the answer to your last question is *yes*.

(What do you keen by everything is fine? In terms of stationarity vs non-stationarity, yea, everything should be fine.)

Comment: Yes, in terms of stationarity, thank you :)

Comment: This is not the whole story. E.g. under cointegration, the residuals will be stationary even though the variables themselves are nonstationary. The coefficient estimates may then have nonstandard distributions, making the vanilla $t$-tests and $F$-tests invalid and the standardly reported $p$-values misleading.